# How can I replace values in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to put the word "null" instead of question marks. How can I do it?
(this is pandas data frame)
{[image: my code and my data frame]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzuNf.jpg)

```
 import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\ASUS\Downloads\bridges.csv' , header=None)
df.columns = ["IDENTIF", "RIVER", "LOCATION", "ERECTED","PURPOSE", "LENGTH", "LANES", "CLEAR-G","T-OR-D", "MATERIAL", "SPAN", "REL-L","TYPE"]
print(df)
```

Comment: Hiva, put your code here, instead of the screenshot, so its easy for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
df = df.replace('?', "Null")
```

Or, you probably actually want to use:

```
import numpy as np    
df = df.replace('?', np.nan)
```

Comment: No worries. In the future if you dont want your question to be downvoted, you should post your code rather than a screenshot.

If you paste your code then press the { } button, it will format it as code.

If this has worked please press the answered tick :)